# What is difference between Solr 1.4 and Solr 3.4

Tags: apache, lucene, solr

mostly its recommended download apache-solr 1.4.1 from http://mirror.lividpenguin.com/pub/apache//lucene/solr/

can you please tell, difference between solr-1.4.1 and 3.4.0? which one i should use?

EDIT: Thanks for help aix, Rayan, Jayendra. I cant tick any as answer, because all are correct. i hope i could tick all answers correct......:) Thanks again

Answer (score 8):

If you don't know you need to go with 1.4.1, choose 3.4.

Seconding what aix said, looking at the changelog, the highlights of 3.4 over 1.4.1 for me are
(from the [Solr home page](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)):

- Solr 3.4

  - Post-group faceting option (group.truncate) can now compute facet counts for only the highest ranking documents per-group. (SOLR-2665).
- Solr 3.3

  - Grouping / Field Collapsing
- Solr 3.1

  - Numeric range facets (similar to date faceting).
  - New spatial search, including spatial filtering, boosting and sorting capabilities.
  - Extended dismax (edismax) query parser with support for fielded queries, enhanced relevancy, and full lucene syntax support.
  - Distributed search support for the Spell check and Terms components.
  - Sort results by any function query.
  - JSON document indexing.

And, of course bug fixes all around and a newer Lucene. And, if you are doing any
[faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters), then Solr 3.4 is strongly recommended
-- search on "Solr3" to see all the facet features not available in Solr 1.4. The date / range
faceting is vastly superior in 3.4.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out the differences for yourself by examining the [changelog](http://mac.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Solr-Changelog-42765.html).

As to which version to use, in the absence of reasons to the contrary it probably makes sense to go with the more recent version.

Answer (score 3):

Would recommended 3.4 as its the stable latest version.

Solr 3.X versions are vast improvements on the 1.4 version.

It includes -

1. New search capabilities  such as query support, function queries,
   analysis, input and output formats.
2. Performance improvements such
   as index segment management and distributed support for
   spellchecking.
3. New search application development options such as
   better range faceting, grouping , suggester and a new
   Velocity-driven search UI, plus spatial search and using Apache
   UIMA.
4. and much much more.

you can find detailed information in the change log.

A [nice article](http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/whitepapers/programmers-guide-open-source-search-search-whats-new-apache-solr-lucene-3-4) explains this in detail.